# Read config settings from PhoneGap app

Tags: ios, cordova, configuration, phonegap-plugins

Apparently I'm terrible at Googling. All I want to do is have the ability to read my web service URL from a config file in my PhoneGap app. Also, be able to modify that value during the build process. Is this named alot different in Xcode? I ***think*** I need to save this value in the plist file. If that's the case, then I can just set a user-setting in my build configuration stuff to have it change depending on which build type, Dev/Release.

If that's true, how do I access this from PhoneGap?

I'm guessing this question will get closed, but where else do I go for help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plist` file for cordova project already depreciate since v2.2. Cordova v2.3 start using `config.xml`.

**Target** > **Edit Scheme**

[image]

Comment: Isn't that for specific cordova values though? I want values that will be used by the iOS app in general. Are you saying that I should be writing all of my configuration values to Cordova's config.xml?

Comment: values for iOS app in general will be stored in plist file. but for cordova setting, will be in config.xml

Comment: Are there any cordova plugins that give access to the config.xml values?

Comment: yes. absolutely. must declare in config.xml in able to run the cordova plugins.

Comment: What's the plugin called? I've been searching for a over a day trying to find that plugin, but couldn't, that's why I started this post.

Comment: what do you mean? what type of plugin you want?

Comment: I need to be able to change my service url path based on the different build/environment that I'm currently running...If i'm running "Debug" version, point to Dev site. If I'm running "Test" version, point to test site, if I'm running Production version, point to production url.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it was possible, just didn't know where. That's what happens when you ask a C# developer to develop in Xcode

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use hooks to accomplish everything that you are trying to do without changing around the config.xml file, but I'm not entirely sure this is supported with Phonegap (it is with Cordova.)

Check out the official help page to use the `/hooks/` folder to modify anything during the build process: https://github.com/apache/cordova-cli/blob/master/templates/hooks-README.md

This blog post also seems pretty useful: http://devgirl.org/2013/11/12/three-hooks-your-cordovaphonegap-project-needs/  it talks about changing things based on the environment and I'm sure it'd be easy to extend that to changing based on dev/release.

You could store the link to your web service probably as a config variable. I'm trying to figure out how you can add a config variable and will report back if I get it. In the mean time you could probably just have something like a server.txt file that you change with hooks.